# How to avoid running two loops if I need the result from the first loop in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have a array in Javascript, I need to for-loop the array to find the min integer, the result need to loop through all of the value.
For example : [1,2,3,4,5]

Then I need to use this integer to do another operation in this array. So I need to do the for-loop again, and do something like : if(i === 1){ //do something }.  The problem is I can't do this in my first loop, because I need to loop through them before I do further operation.

So, the question is, how to avoid writing two loops instead of one in javascript?

Comment: do you have an example of the later code with the number?

Comment: `Math.min.apply(this, [1,2,3,4,5]) === 1`

Comment: `i = 1` is an assignment. This might sound like an academic nitpick, but the difference between `=` and `==` has wasted entire lifetimes of developer effort.

Comment: If you need to know the min value to perform the second operation, then you pretty much _have to_ loop through the array twice (I count the application of `Math.min`, or any of `.map`, `.find`, `.reduce` etc. as looping).

Comment: @mbojko that would actually depend on what the second operation is. Say if he needs to find out the position of the min value in the array he doesn't actually need to loop again.

Comment: var arr = [{"key' : "1", "value" : "apple"}, {"key' : "2", "value" : "orange"}, {"key' : "3", "value" : "lemon"}] 
Let's say I need to find the min of key, then print the value "apple".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With in the comments given data, you could reduce the array with a single loop and pick the object with the smallest `key` value.

This makes only sense for unsorted arrays or where the sorting is unknown.

```js
var array = [{ key: "1", value: "apple" }, { key: 2, value: "orange" }, { key: "3", value: "lemon" }],
    min = array.reduce((a, b) => +a.key < +b.key ? a : b);

console.log(min.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no general answer you could apply to avoid "looping twice". Some problems might just require you to do that. However, for your specific problem, it can be solved in one loop. Here's a very simple example.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "key": "1",
    "value": "apple"
  },
  {
    "key": "2",
    "value": "orange"
  },
  {
    "key": "3",
    "value": "lemon"
  }
];

let minObj = arr[0];
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (+minObj.key > +arr[i].key) {
    minObj = arr[i];
  }
}
console.log(minObj);
```

Of course there are a plethora of ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is I can't do this in my first loop, because I need to loop through them before I do further operation.

You're correct. There is no way to do both as you have to run through the array;

- once to confirm what is the min value
- once again to iterate through each min value

Here is an example showing each required loop and a mutation where we set all the min values to 0

```js
const getMin = (arr) => Math.min(...arr) // First loop
const mutateArrValues = (arr, value, mutation) => arr.map(ent => {
  if (ent === value) {
    return mutation(ent)
  }
  return ent
}) // Second loop

const exampleArr = [3, 5, 1, 8, 2, 1]

const min = getMin(exampleArr)
const mutatedArr = mutateArrValues(exampleArr, min, (v) => 0)

console.log('min = ', min)
console.log('mutatedArr = ', mutatedArr)
```